# Push notification permission not being requested

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Trying to enable push notifications in iOS app. The provisioning profiles for development and distribution have been created.

[image]

The push notification services have been enabled on developer.apple.com

[image]

but the app does not request push notification permissions and does not register  a push id. Further more XCode shows this message in the capabilities tab

[image]

Is the error due to profiles not being set up correctly or somewhere else?

Comment: Please show the related code in your `AppDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this to your `AppDelegate` file?

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))
```

Providing this is in swift